# Can 'can't V' always have the opposite meaning of 'must V'(inference)?

Tags: modal-verbs, negation

> He has great calves. He must run very fast.

is a strong inference using 'must'.

Can the sentence using 'can't' always have the opposite meaning of 'must' (inference)?

> You said he's faster than an ostrich but look, he's limping his leg.
>       He can't run that fast.

I'm not familiar with the above expression as the ones below.

> He must be a good runner
>       That must be true!

> He can't be a good runner.
>       That can't be true!

Am I using all the expressions correctly?

Comment: The plural of "calf" is "calves".  It's one of those irregular nouns.

Answer (score 1):

Let me state up front that the plural of *calf* is *calves*. See also *half*, *halves*, *hoof*, *hooves*, and so on. Very often a noun ending in *f* will change to a *v* for the plural and add *-es*.

Also, we just say *limping*, not *limping his leg.* We already know it's his leg that's limping.

Now, *must* denotes requirement. If you must do something, you are required to do it. *Can* denotes ability. If you can't do something, you're unable to do it. But when using *must* and *can't* in the way that you are using them, they are expressing conclusions that you are drawing. Must is an affirmative conclusion; can't is a negative conclusion.

Suppose person A tells person B this:

> Joe covered (i.e. traveled) five blocks in three minutes. He must be a good runner.

Person A is saying that the evidence suggests to him that Joe is a good runner.

Now, *can't* draws the opposite conclusion. Suppose person B has evidence that suggests that person A has drawn the wrong conclusion:

> B: Joe can't be a good runner, at least he can't be today. I saw him limping this morning. He must have sprained his ankle. Maybe he has a bicycle.
>   A: Well, he must have, because I know he doesn't have a car.

B is saying that other evidence suggests that Joe is *not* a good runner. He then gives an alternative possibility. A then says that he agrees with the conclusion that Joe has a bicycle.

Keep in mind that in casual conversations like this one, people using *must* and *can't* often understand that their conclusions are speculative. Both A and B know that they might not have the evidence necessary to prove their positions. Whether or not the conclusions are speculative depends on context:

> A: Joe and Harry look like brothers.
>   B: Well, Harry is the oldest kid in his family, and Joe is older than Harry, so they can't be brothers.
>   A: I guess not.

Finally, other than the corrections I gave you up top, you are using the expressions correctly. Except one thing:

> Whoever said he was faster than an ostrich *can't* be serious. Nobody can run as fast as an ostrich, whether limping or not.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kotWv4MCxNI) is an example of how fast ostriches can run, for your amusement.